# How to draw a 2D plot on a plane in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a plane game object on the 3D scene and I want to plot 2D graph `z=f(x)=sin kx` (btw, MathJaX does not work in this site), for example, on it. I am very new to Unity, could you tell me what should I do?

Comment: Ah, I learned in school that planes are always 2d. This is the definition of a plane. It may be positioned in a 3d space, but the plane itself is always 2d.

Comment: You can create a texture from the plot data, then apply the texture to the material of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to show a plot.

1. you create a bunch of small gameobjects and piece together lines,
2. you create a Texture2D, and draw into it.
3. When leaving Unity a litte, call Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr() and use D3D calls for this.

I think the 2 is what you might use best.
3. is leaving Unity a little and will not port across target platforms.

It leaves up to you how to do graphics on it. Using only SetPixel is not a really big graphics API.

Here's an example how to load a texture with graphics drawn at runtime.
To use it, create an object, don't forget to assign a material, and attach this script.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawTex : MonoBehaviour
{
    Material mat;
    Texture2D tx;

    void Start()
    {
        MeshRenderer rend;
        rend = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(rend);
        mat = rend.material;
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(mat);

        tx = new Texture2D(128,128,TextureFormat.ARGB32,true);

        // draw stuff.
        for(int y=0;y<128;y++)
        {
            for(int x=0;x<128;x++)
            {
                float a,r,g,b;
                r=g=b=a=0f;
                if( x<20 || y<20 || x>108 || y>108 )
                    {a=1.0f;r=g=b=0.75f;}
                else
                    {a=0.5f;r=b=0.25f+(x/256.0f);g=0.25f+(y/256.0f);}
                tx.SetPixel(x,y,new Color(r,g,b,a));
            }
            tx.Apply(true); // now really load all those pixels.
        }

        mat.mainTexture = tx;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of setting pixel by pixel, is there any way to draw lines?

Comment: I just checked the documentation at 

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html

There are also functions to fill in the whole surface in one call:
    Texture2D.SetPixelData()
    Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData()
    Texture2D.SetPixels()

They all allow you to pass in a block of data to fill the whole texture in one go.
But there is not stuff like line function or similar.

I am sure there are libraries to be found somewhere that can do that and draw into a byte[].